# Getting a customers first order date in WooCommerce Rest API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am currently trying to list all orders with the WooCommerce /orders/v3 API endpoint.

Earlier on I was using an export plugin, but I want to automate the flow, and therefore I want to use the API instead.

I am currently exporting all orders including af customer e-mail. But I want to be able to get the ‘customer first order date’ value.
The plugin I used could get that info for me in my exports - maybe they dod the calculation of the date within the plugin, but if they did not - how do I get these date from the API /orders/v3?

I am thinking one of two ways - my problem is, I simply can’t make them work:

SOLUTION 1 - Custom code in functions.php adding field to the API endpoint

SOLUTION 2 - using the customer e-mail to query the API again for the first order that meets the criteria and get the date.

I don’t think either of then is really ‘perfect’ - and I could be nervous about the extra call / performance, but maybe that is nothing to worry about?